# What is the proper term or name for writing the same equation but in a different form?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a technical term for rearranging math functions or answers in a different form with the same value?

example:  x-2 or 2x-4, 1 or 3/3, etc

Comment: Short answer: no,

Comment: What about $x-2$ and $2x-4?$ Is something missing in your examples?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the term _equivalent_.

Comment: Your examples are unclear; they are not equations (as per your title), and even if we interpret them as $y=x-2$ and $y=2x-4$, these do not represent the same function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call those equivalent (or just equal) expressions. If $A=B$, then you can freely replace occurrences of $A$ and $B$ without changing the value of the surrounding expression; this rule is sometimes called the *substitution property of equality*. Using it is usually self-explanatory, but if you need to describe such a step you can say it's "substitution of equivalent expressions".

In many cases there's a more specific name for the operation, like simplifying or factoring or expanding. None of these words have precise formal definitions; they're just names for things we do (as opposed to names of things we study).